# Calling java from Bash: "Cannot execute binary file"

Tags: bash, shell-script, windows, executable, msys

I have this simple Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar ClosureCompiler/compiler.jar --js ../src/typescript.js --js ../src/ts-compiler.js --js_output_file TSCompiler.js
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run the script using `build.sh` in the MSYS environment under Windows (**64-bit!**):

```
./build.sh: ./build.sh: cannot execute binary file
```

But the command itself works if I type it directly into the command line window!

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's with the script itself and not the command in the script. What text editor did you save the script with, maybe it has lines ending in CR/LF instead of LF?

Comment: @Random832 I have already changed them to LF using Notepad++.

Comment: That's a weird error message: `build.sh` is telling you it can't run `build.sh`?  What's the output of `file build.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file was encoded in `UCS-2 Little Endian` !

Changing the encoding to **`UTF-8 without BOM`** resolved the issue.

Comment: Msys copes with Windows line endings. Cygwin doesn't. Neither copes with weird Windows formats that aren't ASCII-based, such as UCS-2 or UTF-8 with a U+FEFF prepended (which Windows calls a BOM).

Comment: @Gilles I've just tried it using Cygwin: it doesn't work - as you said! The problem is that PowerShell adds a CRLF EOL symbol at the end of the file. Here's my question at SO if someone can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135808/system-io-filewritealllines-adds-newline-at-the-end